# TypeScrpit - How to convert "Observalbe<any>" to "any[]"

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my Angular app I get my data from my database via a web api in a json format with following method in my **xx-service.ts**:

```
//...
getMyItem(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('/api/myItem')
            .map(response => response);
    }
//...
```

Now I would like to implement the sort header in my table of Angular Materials. Therefore I have to use the object MatTableDataSource, but I can't use the shown method **getMyItem**.

I tried to implement it into my **xx-component.ts** like this:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.myItemService.getItem());
```

**getItem() method** in **xx-component.ts**

```
    items = Item[];  
    getItem(): void {
        this.myItemService.getMyItem()
          .subscribe(items=> this.items = items);
  }
```

But I get the error

> Argument of type 'Observalbe' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'any[]'. Property 'includes' is missing type 'Observalbe'.

How do I convert it or which further information do you need?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You can't. You need to subscribe to the observable, and, when the event is emitted by the observable, convert the body of the response to what you want.

Comment: Can you show my how to do? I am sorry but I am completely new to Angular

Comment: Then showing you how to do won't help. You need to read documentation to understand what you're doing. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html

Comment: you need to `.subscribe` to `this.myItemService.getItem().subscribe((data)=>{// do something here with the data you just received})` and maybe `return this.http.get('/api/myItem')
            .map(response => response.json());`

Comment: If I use subsrice I get the error **Property 'map' does not exist on type 'subscription.** I am reading the documentation, but it's hard to me because I am new to that framework and English is not my mother language.

my current code:
`dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.myItemService.getItem()
    .subscribe((data) => { this.items= data }).map(response => response.json()));`

Comment: Are you using http or httpClient? If you use http you should `getMyItem(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get('/api/myItem')
            .map(response => response.json());
    }`
And in your component on `ngOnInit` you should call service and `subscribe to it`  Don't subscribe in service.

Comment: I tried to understand the documentation, but it's hard to me, because English is not my mother tongue. I forgot to show you the getItem() method. I am gonna to update the question. May someone has more hints for me. I would me really grateful!

Comment: I use HttpClient and .json() looks like not supported in that case. Shall I use http?

Comment: No. Again, read the documentation of HttpClient. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Yes, that's what I did.

Comment: If you are using `httpClient` response is already in json. Try like this in your service `this.http.get(some_url).map(response as Item[]>` and change your return type to `Observable<Item[]>` Because in your subscription you are assigning to Item[] array

Comment: Thanks **stojevskimilan**. That was the hin I needed. Thanks a lot to all.

Comment: You are welcome do you understand why this work? I will provide answer

Answer (score 1):

In you services `getMyItem(): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.http.get('/api/myItem')
            .map(response => response as Item[]);
    }`

Dont forget to `unsubscribe` on `ngOnDestroy` 
Here is another solution where you don't need to unsubscribe
In your component create `items$ = Observabe<Item[]>` on `ngInit` `this.items$ = this.myItemService.getMyItem()`  and in your template you use `| async pipe` like this `let item of items | async` and thats it!